# Comparing/Conditional Statement toLocaleDateString()

Tags: javascript, date

I'm doing an app, and I encounter this problem, I thought comparing dates will be that easy but it's not.  My condition inside `if` works well if the dates are of the same year, but if the value is like the value given below, it doesn't the result becomes `true` which should be `false`.  So how do I properly compare this date format I have?

startDate.toLocaleDateString() has a value of `12/24/2016`
endDate.toLocaleDateString() has a value of `01/03/2017`

```
if(startDate.toLocaleDateString() > endDate.toLocaleDateString())
{
            //do this
}
else
{
     //do this
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) directly, because it uses [EPOCH time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is comparable.

> Creates a JavaScript `Date` instance that represents a single moment in time. `Date` objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC.

```
if (startDate > endDate) {
```

It uses [`Date#valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)

> The **`valueOf()`** method returns the primitive value of a Date object.

and returns

> The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date.